# AngularJS - How to get value of select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get the value of the select that I have changed.

So this is my HTML:

```
<label>Select Email Template</label>
        <select ng-change="vm.previewMessage(this)" ng-model="vm.emailSelectedMessage" class="form-control">
            <option ng-repeat="message in vm.messages" ng-if="message.type === 1" ng-disabled="vm.isProcessing" ng-value="message.id">
                {{ message.name }}
            </option>
        </select>
```

and here's my JS:

```
function previewMessage(element) {
  console.log(VALUE_OF_SELECT_HERE);
}
```

Comment: use its model `vm.emailSelectedMessage`

Comment: Thank you for this, I forgot about that. I just tranferred that function from native javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You've bound the model for your `<select>` element to `vm.emailSelectedMessage`, in your component/controller, simply access that property, e.g.:

```
previewMessage() {
    console.log(this.emailSelectedMessage);
}
```

You can also display it within your current template using template binding:

```
<label>Select Email Template</label>
<select ng-change="vm.previewMessage(this)" ng-model="vm.emailSelectedMessage" class="form-control">
    <option ng-repeat="message in vm.messages" ng-if="message.type === 1" ng-disabled="vm.isProcessing" ng-value="message.id">
            {{ message.name }}
    </option>
</select>
<div>{{ vm.emailSelectedMessage }}</div>
```